# Regex - find all matches in a string with conditions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Please help me, I am a regex beginner and I didn't find a soluton.

I have a string like this:

```
(name:"apple",color:"red"),(name:"orange",color:"orange"),(name:"berry",color:"red",color:"black")
```

I would like to find all matches (name) with a "color" condition.
Example if:

> - color is RED, the result is: APPLE and BERRY
> - color is ORANGE, the result is: ORANGE
> - color is BLACK, the result is: BERRY

This is the way I tried:
This lists all of names (apple, orange, berry):

```
name:"(.*?)"
```

This find a match of two "condition":

```
color:"red"
```

But if I try to combine like this..

```
name:"(.*?)color:"red"
```

.. the result is 'apple' and 'orange",color:"orange"),(name:"berry",'

thank you

Comment: Regex is NOT the tool for this job.

Comment: And as an aside, the last time I checked, oranges were... orange, not yellow...

Comment: this is just an example :) .. btw I edit this :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a regex that finds all groups that contain the color, but the name must come before the color

```
\(name:"([^"]*)"[^\)]*color:"red"[^\)]*\)
```

for the string:

```
(name:"apple",color:"red"),(name:"orange",color:"orange"),(name:"berry",color:"red",color:"black")
```

you'll get two matches and the name is in group #1 of each match

Comment: maybe because there is two color "tag" in the string: color:"red",color:"black")

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I'd recommend to use an object instead of a string as an input.

But if you don't have any control on the input, one possibility is to first transform it into an array of arrays. You then can walk through it using standard array manipulation methods, such as `.filter()` and `.map()`.

```js
var str = '(name:"apple",color:"red"),(name:"orange",color:"yellow"),(name:"berry",color:"red",color:"black")';

// sanitize input
str = '[' +
  str.replace(/\(/g, '[')
     .replace(/\)/g, ']')
     .replace(/[a-z]+:/gi, '') +
  ']';

// list = [[ 'apple', 'red' ], [ 'orange', 'yellow' ], [ 'berry', 'red', 'black' ]]
var list = JSON.parse(str);

function getFruits(color) {
  return list.filter(function(o) {
    return o.indexOf(color) > 0;
  }).map(function(o) {
    return o[0];
  });
}

console.log('Red fruits are: ', getFruits("red"));
console.log('Black fruits are: ', getFruits("black"));
```

Here is an alternate version for `getFruits()`, using `.reduce()`:

```
function getFruits(color) {
  return list.reduce(function(a, o) {
    return o.indexOf(color) > 0 ? a.concat(o[0]) : a
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
var regex = /\(name:"([^"]+?)"(?:,color:"[^"]*")*(?:,color:"red")(?:,color:"[^"]*")*\)/g;
```

see https://regex101.com/r/hE5zQ8/4

it works even for a string like that:

```
(name:"apple",color:"red"),(name:"orange",color:"yellow"),(name:"berry",color:"red",color:"black"),(name:"berry2",color:"black",color:"red",color:"brown")
```